# Recommended/Alternative ways of starting a Spring Boot app if config server is down?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Was wondering the recommended way of starting a spring boot app if the Spring cloud config server is temporarily down or unavailable. What would be the approach? I know of the retry configurations, but I am wondering if there is a way to have a 'replica' config server and use that as a failover (or something along those lines).

Comment: I think we cant do this cause in yml file we config only one config server

Comment: Also set fail fast to true and enable retry

Comment: @spencergibb would it be possible to retry with a 'backup' url in the .properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not?
After all, spring-cloud-config server exposes rest API and all the interaction with spring boot microservices is done over HTTP. 
From this point of view, you can scale out the spring cloud config server by providing more than one instance of it all are up-and-running and mapping them to one virtual IP.

If you're running in some kind of orchestrated environment (like kubernetes) it is a very easy thing to do.